# Serve static html file in angular app

Tags: angularjs, routes

I have an angular application such that the routing might look like this:

```
angular.module('app').config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
  $routeProvider

  .when('/', {
    templateUrl : 'views/home.html',
    controller: 'homeController'
  })
  .when('/foo', {
    templateUrl : 'views/foo.html',
    controller: 'fooController'
  })
  .otherwise({
    redirectTo : '/'
  });
  $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
});
```

Now, this may be an overly simple question, but can I serve a static page that is never going to change and needs no added javascript from me without specifying it with a .when route?  For example, say I want to serve Googles Webmaster tools verification like so:

/googlee23dc3443279f430.html

Do I really need to create a .when('/googlee23dc3443279f430.html') route?

EDIT: We also did a server rewrite to make it so that non '/' routes would still serve up the index.html file, as specified in this wiki (and to get html5mode(true) working on page refreshes):

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#how-to-configure-your-server-to-work-with-html5mode

Would be nice not to have to add rewriteconditions each time we want to add a static page

Comment: Why would you need a route? If the static html page exists on disk, just point your browser to the URL of that static page. Angular will have nothing to do with it

Comment: @link64 well, we're using $locationProvider.html5Mode(true) and in order to get that working with page refreshes we did a server rewrite to serve up the app when the route wasn't '/', as specified in this wiki:

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#how-to-configure-your-server-to-work-with-html5mode

Answer (score 1):

if the entire page should be replaced with static html, you can use a link with ng-href (to make it dynamic and data based and not hardcoded) - https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHref